# Passing a value through URL when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to pass a value through URL when I press the refresh button of the page.

I'm passing a value through URL when I access the second HTML page of my project and I'm getting from the second page with no problem.
The problem is when I'm refreshing the second page, I am not able to send that value through URL and access it again.

```
//this is the code from my first page
function setup() {

   var tst = createButton('test');
   tst.position(400, 400);
   tst.mousePressed(function () {
       var val1 = 'dadadad';
       var queryString = '?para1=' + val1;
       window.location.href = 'page2.html' + queryString;
   })
   createCanvas(300, 300);
}

//this is the code from my second page to get the value from URL
function setup() {

  var  key = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
   var index = key.indexOf('=');
   key = key.substring(index + 1);
   console.log(key);
   createCanvas(200, 200);

}
//this is the code to pass the value through URL when the page is refreshed
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   var e = e || window.event;
   if (e) {
       var val1 = 'dadadad';
       var queryString = '?para1=' + val1;
       window.location.href = 'page2.html' + queryString;


   }

   // // For Safari
   // return window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('page2.html?para1=ddadadad');;
};
```

I would like to pass a value through URL when the page is refreshed and to access the value from that URL after the refresh has finished.`enter code here`

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the url search params before refresh? Note you can't change `href` in unload events. What you are probably looking for is using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: I want to change the URL in sathe same way I change when I'm accessing the second page if it's possible.

Comment: Or should I use an API to store the value before the refresh and access it after the refresh is complete?

Comment: That might be simple approach...store in localStorage

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I just implemented this and works very well.